# Вопрос о использовании сайта через код бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, изображения

В хэндлере телеграм-бота, который отвечает за фотографии, считаю, нужно сделать условия для работы с сайтом, с каким-нибудь онлайн редактором. Чтобы можно было как-то изменить фотографию в редакторе через бота. Что нужно задействовать для этого?
Если что, я понял, что можно алгоритм построить на основе стандартной "повторялки с фотографиями", только бот должен прислать уже другую, изменённую.

Comment: для "изменения" фотографий вы можете использовать библиотеку `Pillow`. Что именно нужно сделать с фотографией?

Comment: @5c0rp нужно, чтобы на фотографию накладывался фильтр, или как-то настраивалась яркость и насыщенность. Это пока то, что мне надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import telebot
from PIL import Image
import io

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


def bright(source_img, brightness):
    source = Image.open(io.BytesIO(source_img))
    result = Image.new('RGB', source.size)
    for x in range(source.size[0]):
        for y in range(source.size[1]):
            r, g, b = source.getpixel((x, y))

            red = int(r * brightness)
            red = min(255, max(0, red))

            green = int(g * brightness)
            green = min(255, max(0, green))

            blue = int(b * brightness)
            blue = min(255, max(0, blue))

            result.putpixel((x, y), (red, green, blue))
    return result


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def give_photo(msg):
    file = bot.get_file(msg.photo[-1].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file.file_path)
    new = bright(downloaded_file, 0.5)
    bot.send_photo(msg.chat.id, new)


bot.polling()
```

Это как пример. По [ссылке](https://ru.haru-atari.com/blog/26-write-elementary-image-filters-in-python) вы можете взять готовые фильтры либо же изучив `Pillow` написать свои.

Comment: А яркость может как уменьшаться, так и увеличиваться? Или всё идёт в одну сторону?

Comment: @parrothi прочтите статью что я прикрепил, там это описано